# Displaying only equal array in same index

Tags: java, arrays

What is the right condition for diaplaying only equal elements in my array?

Here is the code.

```
int num[] = new int[5];
int numm[] = new int[5];

for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
  num[x] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Values for num[" + (x + 1) + "]"));
}

for (int x1 = 0; x1 < num.length; x1++) {
  num[x1] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Values for num1[" + (x1 + 1) + "]"));
}

String tosho = "";
for (int a = 0; a < num.length; a++) {
  for (int a1 = 0; a1 < numm.length; a1++) {
    if (num[0] == numm[0]) {
      num[0] =n umm[0];
    } else if (num[1] == numm[1]) {
      num[1] = numm[1];
    } else if (num[2] == numm[2]) {
      num[2] = numm[2];
    } else if (num[3] == numm[3]) {
      num[3] = numm[3];
    } else if(num[4] == numm[4]) {
      num[4] = numm[4];
    }       
  }                
}
tosho += (num[0]) + "" + (num[1]) + "" + (num[2]) + "" + (num[3]) + "" + (num[4]);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "both " + tosho + " found in array.");
```

when I input

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

in the first aary, then

```
1,22,3,4,5
```

in the second array, still it display the `2` or `22`, even though they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

In the second loop you have to initialize `a1` with `a+1`, So that you could get the expected output.

```
boolean f = false;
for (int a = 0; a < num.length; a++) {
  for (int a1 = a+1; a1 < numm.length; a1++) {
    if (num[a] == num[a1]) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num[a]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sir, chANGE code a bit, above.. i want my inputted elements in num[] and numm[] to be compared, if equal, those elements will display in one MESSAGE dialog.

Comment: Then the second loop should start with 0 only.

Comment: yes it should be start in 0;;

now i dont know how to put the EQUAL ARRAYS in some holder so that i can display those.

Comment: Put into some other array or ArrayList.